# Does a slippery liquid leak through pipe fittings?

Tags: organic-chemistry

We use a 6% potassium hydroxide (KOH) solution for electrolysis.  This solution is known to be "slippery".  Does this mean that it will leak/seep through NPT pipe threads more than plain water?

Comment: @JonCuster, it's *not* slippery becuase it *removes* oils, but because it saponifies the fats and oils, changing *skin* to *soap*. That is not at all good for tissues. Sorry if this comment sounds caustic.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - sigh, yes, you are correct. But because it is messing with those oils it is also ripping them out of the near surface layers...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Potassium hydroxide ($\ce{KOH}$) makes skin feel slippery because it [saponifies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saponification) oils in your skin, changing them to *soap*. It is called [caustic potash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_hydroxide) because of the damage it does to tissue.

However, though $\ce{KOH}$ is caustic to *skin*, it does not affect most metallic pipe or, at 6%, PTFE ("Teflon") tape dope, nor is it *much* more likely to leak out (it may lower surface tension somewhat, so leakage would be faster if there is a hole). It *could* cause leaks if there are any glass, aluminum, brass or other materials which it attacks. See this [corrosion chart](https://dixonvalve.com/sites/default/files/documents/corrosion-resistance%20chart.pdf) from Dixon.

BTW, [PTFE *does* dissolve](http://www.standard-ptfe.com/chemical-resistance-guide-of-ptfe-and-filled-ptfe.php) in potassium, and other alkali metals, in liquid ammonia, $\ce{NH3}$. See [O. Lanzi, S. Godfrey answers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34190/is-there-any-chemical-that-can-destroy-ptfe-or-teflon).